# Class 'views_plugin_display' not found

Tags: media

Getting this

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'views_plugin_display' not found in ../sites/all/modules/contrib/media/includes/media_views_plugin_display_media_browser.inc on line 18, referer: ..

Any ideas how I can fix that?

Thanks,
Dmytro

Answer (score 0):

If you have Views enabled, this might be an issue with Media.  This has been [previously reported the issue queue for the project](https://www.drupal.org/node/1423010), and there it was suggested to reinstall the latest version of the Media module, in case the files had become corrupt.